# Mysql adding join subquery to count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I've got two tables Loan and Book.

With this query I count most loaned books from Loan by counting Book_ID:

```
select Book_ID, count(Book_ID) as Count
from Loan
group by Book_ID
order by Count desc;
```

Now I would like to add Book title from Book table here. I have Book_ID as Foreign key in Loan table. I'm not quite sure how to put this query together.

This is what I tried but no results:

```
select Book_ID, count(Book_ID) as Count, Book.Title
from Loan, Book
where Loan.Book_ID = Book.Book_ID
group by Book_ID
order by Count desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ambigious column names since you have joined to another table, try giving them an alias:

```
select Book.Book_ID, count(Book.Book_ID) as Count, Book.Title
from Loan, Book
where Loan.Book_ID = Book.Book_ID
group by Book.Book_ID
order by Count desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that it would make a difference.

Comment: Does that work? If so please click the tick to accept answer, thank you,